# Changing Text based On Selection

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to change text in a text field based on the selection in a drop down list. This is being done in javascript. The following code is what I am trying:

```
var myList = document.getElementById("000");
var myVariable= document.getElementById("111");
var myListValue = myList.options[myList.selectedIndex].value ;

if(myListValue == 1){
myVariable.text = "Hello";
}
```

I have tried comparing with both the value of the drop down list selected value and text... Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry that should be myList

Comment: should that be myListValue == "1" if you are comparing text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to assign a 'value' to a text input, you need to set the 'value' instead of 'text' property:

```
if(myListValue == 1){

    myVariable.value = "Hello";
}
```

see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tfbppg2/1/)